# Get coordinate of point after perspective displacement

Tags: math, three.js

When an ortographic camera is looking to a sphere with center (0, 0, 0) the rightmost point in the sphere is (100, 0, 0). But when a perspective camera is looking to the sphere at some close distance (the whole sphere still can be seen), the rightmost point may be (98, 0, 20), for example.

The "displaced coordinate" is the "inverse projection" of a coordinate. The coordinate (98, 0, 20) appears in the same place as (100, 0, 0) would appear if the camera was orthographic instead of perspective. So the "displaced coordinate" of (100, 0, 0) is (98, 0, 20) in the example.

How do I get the "displaced coordinate" given the point coordinate, the projection matrix and the camera position?

This is useful to know the distance of a pixel to the sphere center independently from the screen size.

Comment: There is no "displacement", you see a different coordinate.

Comment: @prisoner849 I have edited the question. Yes I see a different coordinate, but I'd like to know *which* coordinate I see.

Comment: The vector of [98, 0, 20] has length 100. What you see is where the ray from your perspective camera touches the surface of the sphere, when the ray is a tangent to sphere.

Comment: @prisoner849 I believe that scaling the sphere size by 2 * distance of tangent point to sphere center won't work perfectly because the "distortion" of the projection is bigger at points that are closer to the camera. But I believe that this "approximation" of the perspective distortion will be enough. I have posted [a question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4387775/find-point-where-ray-is-tangent-to-circle) in Math StackExchange about how to find the "tangent point".